# Log4j2 Thread blocking on OutputStreamManager.write

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, spring-boot, log4j2

**Background**
I am using log4j2(2.12.1) with Sync root and Async logger. Lmax ring buffer size is default which is 256*1024. My appender in Console. I am logging MapMessage with JSON layout. Average size of my log message is approx 100 bytes.

With above details I am noticing few threads ar blocked at

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-172" #451
   Thread State: BLOCKED (on object monitor) owned by "http-nio-8080-exec-148" Id=429
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:231)
  - blocked on <0x000000003eb936ae> (a org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.writeBytes(OutputStreamManager.java:206)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractLayout.encode(AbstractLayout.java:211)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractLayout.encode(AbstractLayout.java:37)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:197)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:190)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:181)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:543)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:502)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:485)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.logParent(LoggerConfig.java:534)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:504)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:485)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig.log(AsyncLoggerConfig.java:121)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:460)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:162)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2190)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2144)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2127)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1828)
  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:1282)
```

My question is..

1. Is Ring Buffer is getting full very fast which is causing back pressure to main thread(In . my case servlet container thread which is http-nio-8080-exec-148)? Heap dump shows RingBuffer took 7MB(Before and After test) always.
2. If ring buffer is getting full very fast, how can I increase size of it ? or may be drop events ??
3. Looking at the Log42 performance report I know Console appender is not suggested, But i really dont have a choice here.Is here any better appender which writes to STDOUT?

Any suggestion or thoughts is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That lock is there to prevent multiple threads from writing to the same OutputStream simultaneously as that could cause the data to be co-mingled. Although it isn't guaranteed, many of the OutputStream implementations will lock the calls to write anyway - so even if the lock were removed it would just block in the OutputStream implementation.

This is obviously happening because the OutputStream being used is writing data from some other thread. This thread does not indicate that the ring buffer is full, but it is possible that some other thread is blocked due to that. It isn't clear to me why you must write to the Console but [Logging in the Cloud](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html) provides more data on why you shouldn't do it and what alternatives you have when running in a cloud environment.

**Update**: After reviewing the full thread dump I have some observations:

1. There are many threads waiting at  `com.xxxx.apie.library.InternalRequest.execute(InternalRequest.java:273)`. These appear to be waiting for work to be performed on another thread but it isn't clear from the thread dump exactly what that is.
2. There are several threads logging to the output stream that are blocked. The calls originate from various points in a couple of classes but all are logging at info level.
3. You are using JsonLayout.
4. You didn't post your Log4j configuration but in the stack trace above you can see that AsyncLoggerConfig is calling LoggerConfig's log method. In reviewing the code in AsyncLogger it would appear that you have configured an AsyncLogger that has no Appender References, so the Logger is delegating to its parent, which is NOT an asynchronous logger so the log event is not even being queued to the ring buffer but is being logged directly from the application thread.

The bottom line is that you are logging synchronously to the OutputStream (probably the Console) and threads are blocking on that because the I/O is slow.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.  I still did not understand how the my main thread(Servlet container) which is writing  to the buffer is blocked by a thread which is reading from the buffer and writing it to the Output Stream. That would be possible only if Ring Buffer is full and causing a back pressure on the thread which is writing to the buffer. Also reg cloud logging my infra is bit different. I am using cloud foundry containers to deploy my app and it is integrated with splunk, I have no control over those infrastructure.Logging to STDOUT is not recommended if exceptions are logged

Comment: I am not logging stack traces anyway.

Comment: You only showed the stack trace for a single thread and asked why it was blocked. You didn’t show any other blocked threads so I can’t speculate on them.

Comment: Here is the full thread dump https://so-help.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/threads-dump.txt

Comment: hope that thread dump helps. If not let me know if anything else needed

Comment: you are right about the configuration issue. I never noticed. Regardign```com.xxxx.apie.library.InternalRequest.execute(InternalRequest.java:273)``` it is http request for another service in a separate thread and waiting to get a response.

Thanks you for your help. Much appreciated!!